# Is there any way to improve accuracy of pocketsphinx on speech-recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I have a script that simply converts video to wav format with specific parameters and then transcribers its audio.

```
def video_to_wav(self):
    mp4_video = os.path.join(self.dir, self.name + ".mp4")
    if os.path.isfile(mp4_video):
        subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i {0} -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 {1}.wav".format(
            mp4_video, os.path.join(self.dir, self.name)), shell=True, env=os.environ)
        os.remove(mp4_video)
    else:
        raise SystemError
    return self.name + ".wav"
```

For audio transcription, [PocketSphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) was my choice, but I used it from [speech-recognition](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) library.

PocketSphinx is quite inaccurate unless audio has a very high quality (it barely recognizes the speech with decent/good quality). You can see that conversion parameters are specifically chosen for sphinx recognition:

`ffmpeg -i {0} -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 {1}.wav`

---

Is there anything that I can do to improve accuracy? Perhaps an acoustic model will tune speech recognition accuracy? If so how can I use it with `speech-recognition` module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to improve PocketSphinx's accuracy - for a given sampling rate (i.e Hz) - is to reduce the range of vocabulary you want it to recognize. If you can constrain it to even a few thousand possible words its accuracy improves dramatically. The CMU Sphinx website has tools to help you do this.

Additionally, since you are working with a recording, you can adjust the back-tracing and confidence parameters to give slower but more accurate results.

PocketSphinx includes time-stamps in the text output, and includes notifications when it's confidence on the transcription is low. You could try running two processes - the first pass with a smaller vocabulary and later reattempt those intervals of low confidence with a broader vocabulary in a second pass. You will then have to merge the text transcriptions.

Comment: 16kHz - as you are working with has been acceptable for my work with Sphinx in the past. Be careful when merging stereo (or better) sound streams into one mono stream from a video. Often the center channel has more spoken content, consider the possible value of isolating it for transcription.

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy you can use more advanced toolkit like [Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org). For python ou can check https://github.com/gooofy/py-kaldi-asr.